# EnumDescriptorProto error while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to run the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

print("Hello TensorFlow version", tf.__Version__)
```

It is firing the following error

> Users/anaconda/envs/cnn/bin/python
>   /Users/Downloads/rude-carnie/version.py Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File "/Users/Downloads/rude-carnie/version.py", line 1, in 
>   import tensorflow as tf File
>   "/Users/anaconda/envs/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/init.py",
>   line 24, in  from tensorflow.python import * File
>   "/Users/anaconda/envs/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/init.py",
>   line 52, in  from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import * File
>   "/Users/anaconda/envs/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py",
>   line 10, in  from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2 File
>   "/Users/anaconda/envs/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py",
>   line 735, in  options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR), File
>   "/Users/anaconda/envs/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py",
>   line 501, in new return
>   _message.default_pool.FindFieldByName(full_name) KeyError: "Couldn't find field
>   google.protobuf.EnumDescriptorProto.EnumReservedRange.start"

how can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: What's your `import google.protobuf; google.protobuf.__version__`? And which version of TensorFlow did you try to install?

Comment: im using 3.5.0 version of protobuf and 1.4 v of tensorflow

Comment: Seems like an Anaconda issue. Maybe try pip/virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I came across same problem.
Uninstall all the protobuf on your machine (both from anaconda and pip)

```
pip uninstall protobuf
conda remove protobuf
```

install protobuf using pip:

```
pip install protobuf==3.5.0.post1
```

Source : 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14689